# Can someone purchase a google subdomain?

Tags: domains

Is it possible to buy a sub-domain of Google? 
For example

> blabla.google.com

Comment: How much money are you willing to spend?   Are you looking for open registration of any subdomain for a small yearly fee, or are you asking if somebody offered Google 1 billion dollars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Registrars sell domain names, not sub-domains which are "sub" to the main domain name.

Google, specifically is very protective of their name, as they should, to the point where they also own many variations of goooooooooooogle.com

EDIT: Apparently my last sentence has changed as I see they only own the version with one extra 'o' that I could immediately find.

Comment: Any owner of a name can sell any name under it, for free or not. It is a local policy. Owner of `eu.org` for example provides free subdomains and there are no registrars. Even for TLDs there is not always registrars.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek right, while I doubt most of us could actually *afford* buying a subdomain from Google, it's their call if they want to sell one. (But perhaps you could get a discount for plus.google.com)

Comment: Fwiw: [whois of goooooooooooogle.com](https://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=goooooooooooogle.com&type=domain).

Comment: It would have been so cool if they'd owned the 100-o version.